# QGIS 2.14 standalone GRASS provider missing Msys folder, can't execute tools

Tags: qgis-processing, grass-7.0, msys, qgis-2.14

In QGIS 2.12 and down, when one went about manually setting the GRASS provider folder paths, this was the way to do it
[image]

In GIS 2.14 there is no Msys folder in the same path (...\apps\msys) or any other folder in the QGIS installation. 
[image]

So even though QGIS standalone needs to have it set correctly in order for GRASS tools to work, it can't be done.
[image]
[image]

So how do you make GRASS tools work in QGIS 2.14?

Comment: link for future reference http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14431

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same problem using the Osgeo installer, but I just managed to solve it.

First download this https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/?source=typ_redirect

Install it, look for msys-base package and install it.

Set the path to msys in QGIS to "C:\MinGW\msys" or what ever local drive it was installed on and the Grass algorithms should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Though after I installed it I realized it doesn't matter where the msys folder comes from and how it is installed, and that I already have in my 2.12 installation

Comment: I installed msys but and set the path, but Grass geoalgorithms did not work, used nightly 2.15 did not work either

Answer (score 5):

So here's the deal:
QGIS 2.14 standalone doesn't come with msys installation, but comes with grass 7 folders.
QGIS 2.12 standalone comes with msys and grass 6.4 folders, yet no grass 7.

The solution is as simple as copying the folders from one registry to the other.

I worked with both 2.12 and 2.14 to verify that this works, and it does.

In order to have all the grass functionality working in 2.14, I copied the msys (and grass 6.4) from QGIS 2.12 apps folder to the C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps folder, and set the correct path in the providers setting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on OSX 10.11.3 and I've got the same bug with my 2.12 version downloaded from [Kynchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis).
I just download this [file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/msys-core/msys-1.0.18-1/msysCORE-1.0.18-1-msys-1.0.18-ext.tar.lzma/download), unpack it in the msys folder that I created in the path indicated in processing options box. It seems working fine. I've got 160 Algorithms, I don't remember if it is the expected number, can someone confirm me ?

Comment: Similarly, I'm on OSX10.10.5 with QGIS 2.18.7 with same problem. I tried this suggestion: Within the Grass7 directory, I added msys directory.  I then placed the unpacked msysCORE files in this directory. I exited QGIS and reentered and it still doesn't work. Anyone know what I'm missing?