# QGIS 2.14 Processing plugin crashes - TypeError: must be string, not None

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, debugging, qgis-2.14

I've recently installed 2.14, and it worked fine for the first couple of days ([Appart from Grass tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183261/qgis-2-14-standalone-grass-provider-missing-msys-folder-cant-execute-tools)), including several program and computer reboots.

Today I had this error show up
[image: notification bar]

```
Couldn't load plugin processing due to an error when calling its initGui() method 

TypeError: must be string, not None
```

The full Pyhton error report:
[image: python error box]

The Processing plugin version is 2.12.99. I've tried reinstalling and downgrading the plugin, that didn't work.

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue. I've tried hard to fix it out , but in vain ! can someone please help ? :D

Comment: The same for me.

Comment: I am having the same issue as well - processing plug in worked fine for a couple of hours, then I tried installing Orfeo toolbox and now it gives the same message. Did anyone find a solution? P.S. sorry for giving an answer, rather than commenting but apparently I need 50 reputation in order to comment.