# Grass tools not working in QGIS 2.14.3-ESSEN, OSGEO4W

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-processing, osgeo4w, qgis-grass-plugin

Windows 10

QGIS 2.14.3-ESSEN

OSGEO4W install  (current)

64-bit

Processing toolbox.

**Grass tools do not work**

Neither 6 nor 7. 6 makes sense as I do not see OSGEO4W installing it but 7 tools are not working either.

My Grass folder (7) appears to be C*:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.0.4*

They are activated (I know they are not in the screenshot).
Grass 7 works as a standalone.

[image: screen capture]

Error message:

> Missing dependency. This algorithm cannot be run :-(  The specified
>   GRASS GIS 7 folder does not contain a valid set of GRASS GIS 7
>   modules. Please, go to the Processing settings dialog, and check that
>   the GRASS GIS 7 folder is correctly configured

**What exactly should go in these four yellow boxes?**

Now when I try to manually enter my path to grass 7 I get a new error message (below). No msys folder exists in the latest version of OSGEO4W 64-bit so I cannot set this.

[image: msys error].

This solution ([QGIS 2.14 standalone GRASS provider missing Msys folder, can't execute tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183261/qgis-2-14-standalone-grass-provider-missing-msys-folder-cant-execute-tools)) appears to point to a spam link now and not mysys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used the Advanced Install option in OSGeo4W to make sure msys and GRASS 7 are both installed?

I usually run the express install first, then go back into Setup, tick over to Advanced Install, and grab any extra bits and pieces I like to use.

My GRASS 7 path is **C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.0.4**

GRASS 7 commands work for me but not GRASS commands - doesn't matter to me though.

Answer (score 0):

I moved an old MYSYS folder and contents from an earlier QGIS install. 7 works now. I think for 6 to work Id have to install it and point to it.