# "Points in Polygon" command (vector-analysis tools) doesn't appear in QGIS 2.16

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-processing

I can't find the "Points in Polygon" command under the vector-analysis tools. It is missing from the pull down menu.  Any ideas why?  I just loaded QGIS for the first time on my new PC.

Comment: See also this answer : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-qgis-2-16

Answer (score 6):

This command from FTOOLS is now in the processing panel. Check in the QGIS geoalgorithms folder. I suppose what your are looking for is "Count points in polygon" ? If it doesn't look like mine, check also if "advanced interface" is selected in the dropdown list at the lower part of the panel.

[image: QGIS geoalgorithms]

If you can't find this panel, go to Plugins and check if Processing is checked

[image: install processing]

You can add it inside a button with the Customize Toolbar Plugin :

[image: Customize Toolbar Plugin view]

You'll have it in a toolbar :

[image]

Comment: ok that works...but I cant add the button in toolbar now...I get this error MSG  "wrong value for parameter "Msys folder"   specified path does not exit:

Comment: For your bug, have a try with this answer : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183261/qgis-2-14-standalone-grass-provider-missing-msys-folder-cant-execute-tools I added a way to add your button in a toolbar :) From what I read "Apparently msys is no longer required, so it should not be requested."